# I can't display url tag in template

Tags: python, django

**`views.py`**

```py
def Product_details (request , product_name):
    product_detail = Product.objects.get(pk=product_name)
    return render (request, 'product_detail.html', {
      'product_detail' : product_detail,
})
```

**`urls.py`**

```py
urlpatterns = [

  path('', views.Product_list , name= 'Product_list'),
  path('product/<int:product_name>/', views.Product_details , name= 'Product_details'),
```

**`product_detail.html`**

```html
<a href="{% url 'Product_details' product.name %}
```

I can't display the URL tag on the page.

Comment: `{% url 'Product_details' product.name %}` should be `{% url 'Product_details' product_detail.name %}`.  If that doesn't work, you will need to edit your question showing the `Product` class.

Comment: show me this error now // Reverse for 'Product_details' not found. 'Product_details' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: Add you full urls.py and your `Product` class to better assist you.  Is `Product` name an integer or a string?

Comment: from django.urls import path
from .import views
from django.conf import settings
from .forms import OrderForm
from django.conf.urls.static import static

app_name='Product_list'    
app_name='OrderForm'
app_name = 'SpecialProduct'
app_name = "products"

urlpatterns = [

  path('', views.Product_list , name= 'Product_list'),
  path('product/<int:product_name>/', views.Product_details , name= 'Product_details'),
  path('qa/', views.Question_list , name= 'Question_list'),
  path ('order/' , views.OrderForm , name='OrderForm'),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `urls.py` file, add this variable above urlpatterns:

```py
app_name = "products"
```

and then try accessing it like this:

```html
<a href="{% url 'products:Product_details' product.name %}">click me</a>
```

Comment: If this solved your question @MrAmir then you should accept Hammad's answer by clicking the green ✔️ for his answer.

Comment: i did now .. thank you all . i m new here and in programming

Answer (score 0):

**First** `app_name` should only appear once in a given **urls.py** file.  You are also importing modules that don't seem to be needed in your **urls.py** file.  Right now you seem to have:

```py
from django.urls import path 
from .import views 
from django.conf import settings 
from .forms import OrderForm 
from django.conf.urls.static import static 

app_name = 'Product_list' 
app_name = 'OrderForm' 
app_name = 'SpecialProduct' 
app_name = 'products'

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('', views.Product_list , name= 'Product_list'),
    path('product/<int:product_name>/', views.Product_details , name= 'Product_details'), 
    path('qa/', views.Question_list , name= 'Question_list'), 
    path ('order/' , views.OrderForm , name='OrderForm'),
]
```

So, change the above file to:

```py
from django.urls import path 
from .import views 
 
app_name = 'products'

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('', views.Product_list , name= 'Product_list'),
    path('product/<int:product_name>/', views.Product_details , name= 'Product_details'), 
    path('qa/', views.Question_list , name= 'Question_list'), 
    path ('order/' , views.OrderForm , name='OrderForm'),
]
```

Next, do what [@Hammad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13600944/hammad) suggests:

```html
<a href="{% url 'products:Product_details' product.name %}">click me</a>
```

**Next**
You have `pk=product_name` and `path('product/<int:product_name>/'` which suggest that the product_name is the primary key, and an integer.  The term **name** generally refers to a string, not an integer, which iw why I wanted to see your `Product` class.